# How to remove a random element from a list and add it to another list in python

Tags: python, list, random-access

`list = ['john','james','michael','david','william']`

`winner = []`

How can I remove a random item from `list` and add it to `winner`?

Comment: You might not want to name your variable `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
winner.append(list.pop(random.randrange(0,len(list))))
```

To break this down:

```
random.randrange(0,len(list))
```

will generate a random number between zero and the length of your list inclusive. This will generate a random index in your list that you can reference.

```
list.pop(i)
```

This will remove the item at the specified index (i) from your list.

```
winner.append(x)
```

This will add an item (x) to the end of the winner list. If you want to add the item at a specific index, you can use

```
winner.insert(i,x)
```

with i being the index to insert at and x being the value to insert.

If you want more information, a good reference is the python docs on data structures:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: `list.pop` takes from the end, not a specific index

Comment: @cricket_007 Check out the python docs that I referenced, if an index is not specified it returns the last element, otherwise it returns the element at the specified index

Comment: I was simply pointing out that you didn't provide the parameter in your answer

Comment: +1, good answer. But use random.randrange(), just for code beauty. Then you do not need to subtract 1 from len(list). And, do not use list as a var name. It'll make your answer even better. :D

Comment: Took your advice to use the randrange() function @Dalen, thanks! I left list as the variable name to be consistent with what the asker used in the original question... despite its ugliness :)

Comment: Thanks to you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

This selects a random item from a list of names `names` and adds it to another list `winner`. The chosen winner is then removed from the `names`.

```
import random
winner = []
names = ['john','james','michael','david','william']
winnerindex = random.randint(0,len(names)-1)
winner.append(names[winnerindex])
del names[winnerindex]
print winner, names
```

Comment: What exactly is the question, you want me to elaborate on? @J F

Comment: Yes, so this brilliant piece of code is really sophisticated and uses a lot of rarely known concepts, such that only a minority of users will understand it without a page long documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use random.randint from index 0 to len(list) to get the index of the element of list and append it to winner.

```
import random
index = random.randomint(0, len(list)-1)
winner.append(list[index])
del list[index]
```

Comment: This might cause duplicates to be added

Comment: This doesn't remove the number from the original list.

Comment: @cricket_007 he never mentionned about duplicates.

Comment: Somewhat implied by removing elements from the other list

Comment: @PrestonM thanks for pointing it out i forgot that part of the question while typing my answer !